# How can I open file from terminal (UNIX), in eclipse (Win7)?

Tags: windows-7, unix, ftp, eclipse

I am using Remote System Explorer (RSE) to FTP into my unix server. I see the files on my server. But what I want to do is launch the terminal and *rlogin* into a different machine, and open the file/s in the Win7 Eclipse.

I am using:

- WIn7 Enterprise SP1 x64
- Eclipse Kepler SR1, Build ID: 20130919-0819
- RSE 3.5

Thanks

Comment: From a security perspective, I'd want RSE to use SSH-based SFTP rather than rlogin. Does the other server support SSH?

Comment: yes it does. the terminal itself is connected via ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure your unix server allows SSH.

Remote Systems Panel > "New Connection ..." > Choose "Linux" > Click "Next" > Enter the "Host name" > Enter the "Connection Name" > Click "Next" > Checkbox "ssh.files" and click "next" > Checkbox "processes.shell.linux" > Click "next" > Checkbox "ssh.shells" and click "Next" > checkbox "ssh.terminals" > "Finish".

There will be a new server in the "Remote Systems" Panel.

Right click on "Ssh Terminals" and click on "Launch Terminal". Done!